# Creating Text Field With Dropdown Search

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a text field that has a dropdown menu attached. I want the text field to act as a search function as well as being able to create new dropdown items. Similar to this screenshot:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure how I would achieve this. I've seen one package that is close to this but doesn't quite work in the same way. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_textfield

Comment: That's close but not quite. The functionality is slightly different with the search being inside the dropdown. That means you have to click a second time to be able to search. Somewhat pedantic but from a users point of view would be very annoying. At least to me